# eledmac/eledpar How to determine page number?

Tags: eledmac, eledpar

Maybe this is a simple question. But how do I use the pagenumber in parallel pages text typesetted with `eledpar`? Using `\thepage` yields always page number 1, see this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage. }
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage. }
    \lipsum[2]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage.}
    \lipsum[3]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage. }
    \lipsum[4]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage. }
    \lipsum[5]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage. }
    \lipsum[6]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage.}
    \lipsum[7]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thepage.}
    \lipsum[8]
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `eledmac`/`eledpar`, but rather with the fact that page numbers are stepped when pages are shipped out; until then, the value of `\thepage` will not change.

You have to use the `\pageref` mechanism:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum,eledmac,eledpar}

\newcounter{thispage}
\renewcommand{\thethispage}{\romannumeral\value{thispage}}
\newcommand{\thispage}{%
  \refstepcounter{thispage}\label{THISPAGE@\thethispage}%
  \pageref{THISPAGE@\thethispage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage. }
    \lipsum[1]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage. }
    \lipsum[2]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage.}
    \lipsum[3]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage. }
    \lipsum[4]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage. }
    \lipsum[5]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage. }
    \lipsum[6]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage.}
    \lipsum[7]
    \pend

    \pstart
    \textbf{Here page \thispage.}
    \lipsum[8]
    \pend

    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \pstart Test \pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

The command `\thispage` generates automatically a label and then refers to it for getting the correct page number. This of course requires multiple passes in order to converge (as usual with cross references).

Here's the start of page 4

[image]

Comment: in the specific case, that is something to do with eledpar: the pages are not shiped out when \pstart is called, but when the `\pstart...\pend` paragraph is called, but when the `\Pages` is called.

Comment: in general @LaTechneuse thinks one think about counter and macro value with eledpar: when you have problem, is it in many case because of the difference between the call of a pstart and the print of it.

Comment: @Maïeul It's the same problem anyway; `\thepage` is not guaranteed to expand to the correct page number unless at the explicit start of a new page.

Comment: yes, but in the case of eledpar, we are sur that it can't. In many case, \thepage expanded the good way...

Comment: Yes, thank you both. Indeed I needed to understand that with `eledpar`, call of `\pstart` is separate from printing of `\pstart`

Comment: but yes @egreg I understand better what you said now. That is logical.

Comment: and so the @egreg information about \thepage is general, while my information about eledpar is still available.